# How to Remove Retake step in UIImagePicker?

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

I do not want to show Retake step in my iphone application.

how?? subclassing uiimagepicker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't subclass `UIImagePickerController`. It's a bunch of view controllers packaged in a `UINavigationController` subclass.

I don't think you can skip the `Retake` step. Use the [`AV Foundation framework`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/00_Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH1-SW3) instead.

Answer (score 1):

UIImagePickerController calls its delegate's didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo immediately after taking a picture if it has 'showsCameraControls' set to false.